# How to proxy websocket connections to other websockets in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, websocket

I need to create a small authentication layer on top of a 3rd party web-socket based chat application. I have a simple API (get) that can validate api tokens from requests. What I want to do is essentially validate their token (which I know how to do) then proxy the websocket connection to the actual chat server.

I've been looking for solutions and [this thread](https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-node/issues/14) seems to give some pointers in the right direction however I can't get any of the solutions to work.

```
var http = require('http'),
    WebSocket = require('faye-websocket'),
    conf = require('./conf.json');

var server = http.createServer();

server.on('upgrade', function(request, socket, body) {
  console.log('upgrade fired');
  var frontend = new WebSocket(request, socket, body),
      backend  = new WebSocket.Client('ws://echo.websocket.org');

  frontend.pipe(backend).pipe(frontend);
});




server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connection')
  backend = new WebSocket.Client('ws://echo.websocket.org');
  console.log(backend);
  socket.pipe(backend).pipe(socket);
})



server.listen(conf.port);
console.log('Listening on '+port.conf);
```

The connection event is fired, however the upgrade event which is supposed to be fired on a ws connection never is.

The goal is to first authenticate a api key to an external server, then open a proxy to the chat websocket all through a request to this node server via a websocket connection. I'll most likely pass the api key as a get parameter for simplicity. I also looked at [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#proxying-websockets) and attempted using it however it didn't work as well.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Exactly the code I needed to complete a proxy I'm working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being with nginx. I forgot I was proxying requests through the reverse proxy and by default nginx does not support the ws:// connection so it drops it.